# Skip White spaces in a comma separated string when using regular expression to split the string

Tags: regex, string, plsql

I'm using this **[[:alnum:]]{0,},**  regular expression to split this string by the comma 3,5,7 test, and getting following results.

- Match 1 : 3,
- Match 2 : 5,
- Match 3 : test,

**But Match 3: should be '7 test,'**
How to change this repression to skip the white space and fetch the correct values.

Comment: Do you want the comma in the match? Why does 3 not have a comma but the others do?

Comment: Are letters, digits, comma and space the ONLY characters that may appear in your input strings? Or are there also other characters - and if so, what do you need to do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_substr('3,5,7 test,','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('3,5,7 test,', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures any character before a comma (including the comma) until it gets to a comma.

```
[^,]*,
```